# I have a List of Widgets and I want to update the properties of a specific widget inside the List

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have Created a list and an Add Button When user clicks on ADD button a widget is Created and Added to the Widget List.

Image of Output which has list of Predefined widgets on the left and an instance of that widget is created and shown on the right side when user clicks on Add Button : -

[image]

Now I want to edit the properties of those widgets on the right .For example making the text Bold or Add value to textfield or changing the Text on the Button or defining what happens on onPressed event dynamically

Here is the code for Both the classes

PredfinedFileds.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PreDefinedFields{

  static Text textCustom= Text("New Text");
  static TextFormField textFieldCustom= TextFormField(
  );
  static ElevatedButton elevatedButtonCustom= ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("New Button"));
  
}
```

CustomizableForm.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'PreDefinedFields.dart';

class CustomizableForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomizableForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomizableForm> createState() => _CustomizableFormState();
}

class _CustomizableFormState extends State<CustomizableForm> {
  static bool isBold=false;
  List fieldList=[];
  List widgetList=[];

  var text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

void ShowDilogText(isBold){




  showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierLabel: "Barrier",
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 440,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          child: SizedBox(child: Container(
            child: Center(child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                isBold != isBold;
              },
              child: Text("Bold"),
            ),),
          )),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) {
      Tween<Offset> tween;
      if (anim.status == AnimationStatus.reverse) {
        tween = Tween(begin: Offset(-1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
      } else {
        tween = Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
      }

      return SlideTransition(
        position: tween.animate(anim),
        child: FadeTransition(
          opacity: anim,
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}



TextEditingController dateController=  TextEditingController();
    TextField datePickerField=TextField(
        controller: dateController, //editing controller of this TextField
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), //icon of text field
            labelText: "Enter Date" //label text of field
        ),
        readOnly: true,  // when true user cannot edit text
        onTap: () async {
          //when click we have to show the datepicker
          DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: DateTime.now(), //get today's date
              firstDate:DateTime(2000), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
              lastDate: DateTime(2101)
          );
          if(pickedDate != null ){
            print(pickedDate);  //get the picked date in the format => 2022-07-04 00:00:00.000
            String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate); // format date in required form here we use yyyy-MM-dd that means time is removed
            print(formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2022-07-04
            //You can format date as per your need

            setState(() {
              dateController.text = formattedDate; //set foratted date to TextField value.
            });
          }else{
            print("Date is not selected");
          }
        }
    );







    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
//For Predefined Fields
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                      title: const Text("Text"),
                      trailing:  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                        fieldList.add('Text');
                        widgetList.add(PreDefinedFields.textCustom);
                        setState(() {
                          print(fieldList);
                        });
                      }, child: Text("+ Add")),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                      title: const Text("Text Field"),
                      trailing:  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                        fieldList.add('TextField');
                        widgetList.add(PreDefinedFields.textFieldCustom);
                        setState(() {
                          print(fieldList);
                        });
                      }, child: Text("+ Add")),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                      title: const Text("Button"),
                      trailing:  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                        fieldList.add('Button');
                        widgetList.add(PreDefinedFields.elevatedButtonCustom);
                        setState(() {
                          print(fieldList);
                        });
                      }, child: Text("+ Add")),
                    ),

                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                      title: const Text("Date"),
                      trailing:  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                        fieldList.add('Date Picker');
                        widgetList.add(datePickerField);
                        setState(() {
                          print(fieldList);
                        });
                      }, child: Text("+ Add")),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //For Form
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                    ),
                  child: Form(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: fieldList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index){
                            if(fieldList[index]=='Text'){
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    PreDefinedFields.textCustom,
                                    Spacer(),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                                      ShowDilogText(isBold);
                                      setState(() {
                                        final tile = widgetList.firstWhere((item) => item[index]);

                                      });
                                    }, icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                                    }, icon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.red,))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }

                            if(fieldList[index]=='Date Picker'){
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                        width: 400,
                                        child: datePickerField),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.red,))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            if(fieldList[index]=='TextField'){
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                        width: 400,
                                        child: PreDefinedFields.textFieldCustom),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.red,))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            if(fieldList[index]=='Button'){
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    PreDefinedFields.elevatedButtonCustom,
                                    Spacer(),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.red,))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            return Container();
                          })

                  ),
              ),
                )],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```